# Reliable method of embedding flash in SmartTV application

Tags: javascript, flash, samsung-smart-tv

I'm developing an application on a Samsung SmartTV platform, which features a music player. Music is intended to be played through a Flash plugin. I can't seem to figure out a best way to embed this plugin onto a scene.

I tried [this official tutorial](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/View/Developer_Documentation/Samsung_SmartTV_Developer_Documentation_3.1/Flash/Create_Flash_Applications/Tutorial_Creating_Flash_Applications/Task_Flash_Application) from Samsung which places `<object>` into the `<head>` - it works for 2011 sets, on 2012 sometimes app does not even start, but when it does, no flash object is displayed. 2010 sets does not work at all - shows Flash icon instead of actual content.

When i put `<object>` out of the `<head>`, it shows "Unsupported object".

Has anyone determined a reliable method of embedding flash plugin, that works on all versions of SDK?

Comment: About the flash icon in 2010 models - try to use swf published for Flash Player 9. If it is newer than FP9 it won't work.